# Copying memory of adresses with memcpy

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

### Base function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T** shifting (T* in, int size, int dist, int pos) {
    auto out = new T* [size];
    int k = (pos-1) * size/dist;
    for (int i{0}; i < size; ++i) {
        if (i+k >= size) {
            out[i] = &in[k+i-size];
        } else {
            out[i] = &in[k+i]
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

This function is creating an array of pointers *out* to elements of array *in* in a specific order, I wondered if there would be a faster approach with memory manipulation, so I tried something different.

### New function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T** stuff(T* in, int size, int dist, int pos) {
    int helper = size/dist;
    auto out = new T* [size];
    for (int i{0}; i < dist; i++) {
        if (pos + i < size) {
            memcpy(out + i - pos + dist, in+i*helper, helper * sizeof(T*));
        } else {
            memcpy(out + i - pos, in+i*helper, helper * sizeof(T*));
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

However this is not giving an array of adresses, but rather converts the values behind the addresses to pointers so I get the value of the element as a pointer.
On closer inspection this behaviour should not be otherwise, but I can't think of a way to get it to work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new loop body (before your edit, but my analysis remains basically the same) is:

```
memcpy(out + i - pos + (pos + i < size ? dist: 0), in+i*helper, helper * sizeof(T*));
```

Expanding that for readability (which will not hurt performance, so you should do it too):

```
T** dest = out + i - pos + (pos + i < size ? dist: 0);
T* src = in + i * helper;
memcpy(dest, src, helper * sizeof(T*));
```

By writing it out with types, now you can see that the types are not compatible (T** and T*).  What you're trying to do is copy addresses to particular locations of `in`, but you can't do that in chunks like this because those addresses don't exist as numbers in memory yet, you need to create them!

Your best bet is to stick with your original code, which is clearer.  If there is a performance problem, tell us what level of optimization you're compiling with, what are the input sizes you're using, what is the time taken by this function, and how much is your time budget?

Comment: Actually just 'joking' around, my array size is 40 and the memory thing, I tried, because I came up with it after I designed the first one, but if there's a nice way to manipulate memory of addresses, let me know!

Comment: One more thing, if I cast `src` to `int**` it does not work either, it actually does exactly the same. Why is that?

Comment: With an array size of 40 it's pretty clear you don't have a performance problem at all.  Casting can't solve the problem, because the numbers you want to put into `out` do not exist anywhere in memory, hence cannot be copied.  It's basically "How do I fill an array with [1, 2, 3, 4, ...] using memcpy" and the answer is "You can't."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's exactly what you're looking for, but this will run a bit faster and is somewhat easier to read, and reason about.

```
template <typename T>
T** shifting (T* in, int size, int dist, int pos) {
    auto out = new T* [size];
    int k = (pos-1) * size/dist;

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = k; i < size - k; ++i, ++j)
        out[i] = &in[j];

    for (j = 0; i < size; ++i, ++j)
        out[i] = &in[j];

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Looks neat, thank you!

Comment: @Raumschifffan You should maybe use std::rotate(), which does exactly that.

Comment: Uff, that thought process took me a bit of time, this is hitting hard but thank you nevertheless..

Comment: Oh wait, I realized I actually need an array of pointers, not the rotated array itself.

Answer (score 0):

I finally actually managed to get a solution.

Struct for 'simplifying' datatypes e. g. `int (*) [3]` -> `int` (Note: `t* (*) [n]` -> `t*`):

```cpp
template <typename t> struct rip {
    typedef t type;
};
template <typename t, size_t n> struct rip <t (*) [n]> {
    typedef t type;
};
```

Actual function:

```cpp
template <typename pArr>
pArr shift(pArr pa_in, size_t pos, size_t spl) {
    typedef typename rip<pArr>::type t;

    size_t b_in{sizeof(*pa_in)};
    size_t b_spl{b_in/spl};
    size_t n_spl{b_spl/sizeof(t)};

    auto pa_out{(pArr)malloc(b_in)};
    auto p_out{(t*)pa_out};
    auto p_in{(t*)pa_in};

    size_t i, k;
    for (i = 0, k = pos; k < spl; i++, k++)
        memcpy(p_out + i*n_spl, p_in + k*n_spl, b_spl);
    for (i = pos, k = 0; i < spl; i++, k++)
        memcpy(p_out + i*n_spl, p_in + k*n_spl, b_spl);

    return pa_out;
}
```

Note: `pArr` is expecting type `t (*) [n]` (e. g. `int* (*) [10]`)

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I just rewrote the function that I did not want in the first place…